# Have access to a button that is located inside a collections view cell from a collectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewController class and a UICollectionViewCell class that is dequeued inside my CollectionView `cellForItemAt`. I have a button inside my cell and I want to have access to this button inside a function that is located in my collection controller but I don't want to reference this button from inside `cellForItemAt`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you created a custom UICollectionViewCell that contains a UIButton ?

Comment: Yes I have created a uicollectionviewcell that contains a UiButton

Comment: So you want to access your Cell from the viewController and not from cellForItemAt ?

Comment: Yes that is what I want.How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your `UICollectionViewCell` from the `UIViewController` use:

```
if let cell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: theCellIndex, section: 0)) as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
// here you could access your cell.button
}
```